# Arnold Cat map Decryption code

Tags: matlab, image-processing, encryption

[image]

This is my code for implementing Arnold Cat map for shuffling the pixels.
Here `ite` denotes the number of iterations I need.

For example if I set the `ite` variable equal to 1 then after the encryption I am not getting the original decrypted image, there seems to be a strip occuring at the right and at the bottom of the image. When I am increasing the number of iterartions this effect seems to be quite big because it is sometimes decrypting my image in four pieces and things like that.Another thing also that when I am giving the iterations `count = 96`, the original image=encrypted image =decrypted image.

I know that's because of the periodic property of the Arnold cat Map,but if my decryption code is not working properly for `ite=1` then why is it working properly for `ite=96`.

Please somebody help.
This is frustrating for me
The +1 in the code is done for avoiding out of bounds array index.

```
[row,col]=size(im);
temp=1;
while(temp<=ite)
    for i=1:row
        for j=1:col
            newcord =[1 1;1 2]*[i j]';
            nrowp=newcord(1);
            ncolp=newcord(2);
            encim(i,j)=im(mod(nrowp,row)+1,(mod(ncolp,col)+1));
        end
    end
    temp=temp+1;
    im=encim;
end
temp=1;
while(temp<=ite)
    for i=1:row
        for j=1:col
            nrowp=i;
            ncolp=j;
            newcord =[2 -1;-1 1]*[nrowp ncolp]';
            nrowp=newcord(1);
            ncolp=newcord(2);
            deccim(i,j)=encim((mod(nrowp,row)+1),(mod(ncolp,col)+1));
        end
    end
    temp=temp+1;
    encim=deccim;
end
```

Comment: Could you at least explain what your code does and add some comments? Also adding the reference you used for implementing this algorithm would help a lot. Also please add some example outputs and expected outputs.

Comment: this is code that shuffles the pixels of the image https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold's_cat_map.I have uploaded the decrypted image as you can see the lines at the right and the bottom.This is the issue

Comment: I suggest replacing all `mod(x,y)+1` with `mod(x-1,y)+1` and try again. note that MATLAB's indices are `1`-based, not `0`-based.